# How do I get the amount of internet data used throughout the day?

Tags: linux, networking, scripting, internet, bandwidth

I need to set a cap to my internet usage and manage data usage to download things programmatically based on the amount of data I have consumed.

Is there a way to find out how much internet data I have used since the start of the day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amount of data through your network interfaces are readable in the pseudo-file `/proc/net/dev`. These are statististics since the last reboot so you would have to

1. grab the value at the beginning of each day.
2. worry about reboot during the day (but you can save the contents of the file somewhere before you reboot).